# How to search for specific keywords in posts using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When using the [graph api feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed) to display feeds from a FB page, is it possible to pass in specific keywords to the query and only return those message posts containing those keywords?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. Public Post Search is deprecated, and there is no way to search for keywords in a specific Page Feed either. Just get all the posts, chache them in your database and do the seach on your own.